# Minecraft arrows with custom effects, choose what tipped arrow you shoot?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm building on a custom map and want to have custom arrows with special effects, like an explosive arrow, a thunder arrow and more... I know I can use tipped arrows with diffrent potion effects and have a tipped arrow with instant damage effect as an explosive arrow, and an tipped arrow with poison effect as an thunder arrow...

I'm not really sure how to separate the tipped arrows from each other but I'm pretty sure I can do it with NBT, because tipped arrows with diffrent potion effects have diffrent NBT's? I really hope they have :)

I also am wondering how can I make it so the player is able to choose what tipped arrow the bow will shoot. I tested to have some random tipped arrows in the inventory and it looks like it shoots a random arrow. :(

My idea is to have it like when the player throws the bow it changes what arrow it shoots, but I don't know how to do that... I know how to detect when the player throws the bow but how to change what arrow the bow shoot!!

If you know a data-pack that can do this, please send a link to it :)

Answer (score -1):

You have to do this with commands! There are no explosive arrows in minecraft, I think this video may be what your looking for :)

you can change the end of the command to Thunder, TNT, Even pigs or other animals!